# Specify regex string in JSON, use it in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, json

I am having this entry in a `JSON` file of mine:

```
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "field": "ingame",
            "rules": [
                {
                    "condition": "minLength",
                    "argument": 1,
                    "php": false
                },
                {
                    "condition": "maxLength",
                    "argument": 24,
                    "php": false
                },
                {
                    "condition": "zeroRows",
                    "argument": "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ingame = ?",
                    "php": true
                },
                {
                    "condition": "regexCheck",
                    "argument": "[a-zA-Z0-9_\\(\\)]{1-24}",
                    "php": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It is correct `JSON` according to online parsers.

What I mean with the specific `regex` under `"condition": "regexCheck"` is: A string consisting of 1-24 symbols that are either being `a-z`, or `A-Z`, or `0-9`, or `_`, or `(` or `)`.

How I apply it in JavaScript:

```
function checkRule(condition, argument, value) {
    var pass = false;
    var errormessage = "";
    switch (condition) {
        case "regexCheck":
            pass = value.match(new RegExp(argument));
            if (!pass) {
                errormessage = "Not in expected format";
            }
            break;
    }
    return {
        pass: pass,
        errormessage: errormessage
    };
}
```

However the regex does not seem to be working, and when inspecting the `RegExp` object I see the following: `[a-zA-Z0-9_\(\)]{1-24}`.

**Does anyone know what is wrong with it?**

Also, in PHP I use the following:

```
function checkRules($rules, $name, $value) {
    $pass = false;
    $errormessage = "";
    if (file_exists("../rules/{$rules}.json")) {
        $rules = json_decode(file_get_contents("../rules/{$rules}.json", true));
        foreach ($rules->rules as $fvalue) {
            if ($fvalue->field == $name) {
                foreach ($fvalue->rules as $ruleset) {
                    switch ($ruleset->condition) {
                        case "regexCheck":
                            $pass = preg_match($ruleset->argument, $value);
                            if (!$pass) {
                                $errormessage = "Not in expected format";
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    if (!$pass) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                $pass = true;
                $errormessage = "";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $pass = false;
        $errormessage = "Internal error";
    }
    return array($pass, $errormessage);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `value` when applying the regex?

Comment: @Danny A normal string, for example `"skiwi2"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a hyphen in a quantifier. You have `{1-24}`

Change it to `{1,24}`

Also note, the regex coming back when inspecting the RegExp is correct because `\` is a reserved escape character in JSON.

Comment: I should note that the JavaScript part only works correctly as expected when I use: `pass = new RegExp(argument).test(value);`.